# SQL query to get value from the table for a record and update the fetched value for different record in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Please help me with the SQL query. Every day, I am getting data as shown below -

[image]

where left column is Msisdn and right column is Reference Msisdn.
For each msisdn, I have to find booking_id(column) of the reference msisdn in a table_msisdn and then have to update that booking_id for the msisdn in the left column. I am using below queries.

```sql
select booking_id from table_msisdn where msisdn = '<any reference msidn>';
```

It will give me the booking_id let's say 100.
then I have to update this value for the corresponding msidn in the same table using below query.

```sql
update table_msisdn set booking_id = '100' where msisdn = '<msisdn>';
```

Columns in table_msisdn - msisdn (Primary key), ndc_id, state_allocation, booking_id, subscription, locking_id, reservation_id.

I have to do it one by one for many number of records. Please help me with the sql query so that I can do it at once (using oracle DB). Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show ALL the tables DDL and all sample data

Comment: Hi @OldProgrammer, I have added the column names for table_msisdn. I cannot show the data from table as it is work related.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not  a part of the answer.
Sample data (if I got it right from the question):

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  4916094659983 "ID", 100 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  491763998189  "ID", 200 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  491728303243  "ID", 300 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  491728303239  "ID", 400 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  4915904335947 "ID", 500 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  495904335950  "ID", 600 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  4915904875000 "ID", 700 "BOOKING_ID" From Dual 
        ),
    ref_tbl AS
        (
            Select 4916094659983 "ID", 4915904335947 "REF_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 491763998189  "ID", 495904335950  "REF_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 491728303243  "ID", 4915904875000 "REF_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 491728303239  "ID", 4915904875000 "REF_ID" From Dual 
        )
```

Within the update statement there is a subquery connecting ID, REF_ID and BOOKING_ID. Having these data together solves the problem of seting the new value and filtering the rows to be updated.
Subquery with data...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, 
  (SELECT BOOKING_ID FROM a_tbl WHERE ID = rt.REF_ID) "BOOKING_ID",
  rt.REF_ID
FROM a_tbl t
INNER JOIN a_ref_tbl rt ON(rt.ID = t.ID)
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  
--             ID   BOOKING_ID         REF_ID
--  -------------   ----------  -------------
--  4916094659983          500  4915904335947
--   491728303239          700  4915904875000
--   491763998189          600   495904335950
--   491728303243          700  4915904875000
```

Update ....

```sql
UPDATE a_tbl t
SET t.BOOKING_ID = Nvl  ( 
                            (  
                                SELECT DISTINCT tbl_lnk.BOOKING_ID 
                                FROM 
                                (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, 
                                            (SELECT BOOKING_ID FROM a_tbl WHERE ID = rt.REF_ID) "BOOKING_ID",
                                            rt.REF_ID
                                    FROM a_tbl t
                                    INNER JOIN a_ref_tbl rt ON(rt.ID = t.ID)
                                ) tbl_lnk
                                WHERE tbl_lnk.ID = t.ID
                            )
          , t.BOOKING_ID)
WHERE
    t.ID = Nvl  ( 
                        (  
                            SELECT DISTINCT ID 
                            FROM 
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, 
                                        (SELECT BOOKING_ID FROM a_tbl WHERE ID = rt.REF_ID) "BOOKING_ID",
                                        rt.REF_ID
                                FROM a_tbl t
                                INNER JOIN a_ref_tbl rt ON(rt.ID = t.ID)
                            ) tbl_lnk
                            WHERE ID = t.ID
                        )
             , 0)
--  
--  4 rows updated.
--
```

And the result ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM A_TBL
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--
--             ID   BOOKING_ID
--  -------------   ---------
--  4916094659983         500
--   491763998189         600
--   491728303243         700
--   491728303239         700
--  4915904335947         500
--   495904335950         600
--  4915904875000         700
```

Hoping that I understood the question right. Regards...